# Creating multiple charts in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to display one chart per question that is loaded if the answers I get from server are numbers. The problem is that I am only able to display a chart on the last question. Any idea of how to display one chart per question? Thanks in advance.

```
function chooseSurv(number, name) {
  var j = number;
  var question = new Array();
  question = survQuestions[j];
  var questionType = new Array();
  questionType = survType[j];
  var outputans = "";
  var outputchart = "";
  var SurveyAnswer = Parse.Object.extend("someclass);
  var query = new Parse.Query(SurveyAnswer); query.descending("createdAt"); query.include("author"); query.include("survey"); query.equalTo("survey", somestring); query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      for (var u = 0; u < question.length; u++) {
        var questions = question[u];
        outputans += '<div id="ansbox">';
        if (questionType[u] / 1) {
          var divid = "chart_div" + j + u;
          console.log(divid);
          outputans += '<div id="' + divid + '" class="chart-box"></div>';
          outputans += '</div>';
          for (var k in results) {
            var answer = results[k].get("data")[u];
            var author = results[k].get("author");
            var name = author.get("name");
            outputans += '<h4>' + name + '</h4>';
            outputans += '<p>' + answer + '</p>';
            outputans += '</div>';
          }
          // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
          google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart']
          });
          // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
          // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
          // draws it.
          function drawChart() {
            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows([
              ['Mushrooms', 3],
              ['Onions', 1],
              ['Olives', 1],
              ['Zucchini', 1],
              ['Pepperoni', 2]
            ]);
            // Set chart options
            var options = {
              'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
              'width': 400,
              'height': 300
            };
            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(divid));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            console.log(divid);
          }
        } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

the *real answer* is here --> [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/5090771)...

basically, `divid` changes with each loop. and when finished, points to the last version of `u`.
which the chart function then tries to use...

---

several ways to avoid, but a little restructuring should do the trick...

**first**: `google.charts.load` and `setOnLoadCallback` were designed to be run *once per page load*

not every time a chart should be drawn

try loading google first, then continue with the rest

removing the closures, or functions, from `success` -- should correct the problem

see following snippet...

```
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  'callback': chooseSurv,
  // Set packages to use
  'packages': ['corechart']
});

function chooseSurv(number, name) {
  var j = number;
  var question = new Array();
  question = survQuestions[j];
  var questionType = new Array();
  questionType = survType[j];
  var outputans = "";
  var outputchart = "";
  var SurveyAnswer = Parse.Object.extend("someclass);
  var query = new Parse.Query(SurveyAnswer); query.descending("createdAt"); query.include("author"); query.include("survey"); query.equalTo("survey", somestring); query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      for (var u = 0; u < question.length; u++) {
        var questions = question[u];
        outputans += '<div id="ansbox">';
        if (questionType[u] / 1) {
          var divid = "chart_div" + j + u;
          console.log(divid);
          outputans += '<div id="' + divid + '" class="chart-box"></div>';
          outputans += '</div>';
          for (var k in results) {
            var answer = results[k].get("data")[u];
            var author = results[k].get("author");
            var name = author.get("name");
            outputans += '<h4>' + name + '</h4>';
            outputans += '<p>' + answer + '</p>';
            outputans += '</div>';
          }

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
          data.addRows([
            ['Mushrooms', 3],
            ['Onions', 1],
            ['Olives', 1],
            ['Zucchini', 1],
            ['Pepperoni', 2]
          ]);
          // Set chart options
          var options = {
            'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
          };
          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(divid));
          chart.draw(data, options);
          console.log(divid);
        } else {
```

---

**note**:  the `callback` can be placed in the `load` statement

charts can be drawn anytime, once the `callback` has been called

this `callback` can be used *instead of*...

`$(document).ready(function(){});`

-- and / or --

`window.addEventListener('load',  function () {},  false);`

Comment: Hmm.. That caused the part after  "//Instantiate and draw..." to not work

Comment: No, nothing in the console.